# Django Heroku Postgresql ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: django, postgresql, database-restore, heroku-postgres

I am using Django with Heroku Postgreql. I use both English and Turkish languages on default DB settings. My DB works with no issues both locally and on Heroku. However, I get an error when I try to dump and restore a db from local to production.

```
psql -U user -d db_name -f "b003.dump"

psql:b003.dump:270: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First guess: Encoding mismatch

Your file `b003.dump` is not in the UTF-8 encoding.

You will need to override the encoding settings, specifying the correct text encoding for the file.

It's probably iso-8859-9 if it has Turkish text, though 0xa3 is the pound symbol (£) in many of the ISO-8859 encodings.

Try:

```
PGCLIENTENCODING="iso-8859-9" psql ....
```

I also suggest checking the output of the `locale` command to see what your system default encoding is, and of `file -bi b003.dump` to try to guess the encoding.

### Second guess, after comments revealed `file` output

Your file isn't an SQL script style dump. It a PostgreSQL custom database dump. That's why `file` says:

```
b003.dump: PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.12-0
```

Restore it with the `pg_restore` command.

```
pg_restore -f b003.dump -d db_name -U user
```

At some point I want to enhance `psql` so it tells you this, rather than failing with an error.

The weird thing here is that you must've had a *lot* of previous errors, before the one you showed here, if it's a custom dump.

Comment: I get this error psql:b003.dump:270: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""
LINE 1: %/??F

Comment: Where did the dump come from? What version of PostgreSQL did it come from, and what version are you restoring it to? This suggests the dump file could actually be damaged. Also, what's the output of `file -bi b003.dump` ?

Comment: My local DB is: 

PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn), 64-bit

But dump comes from Heroku Postgres

Comment: And the second question, `file -bi b003.dump` output? You should also check what is on line 270 of the dump.

Comment: file -bi b003.dump >>> regular file and file b003.dump >>> b003.dump: PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.12-0

Comment: pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U user -d db_name b003.dump worked

Comment: That last command should be
````pg_restore -d db_name -U user b003.dump````

````pg_restore```` threw an error saying that it doesn't allow the use of ````-f```` and ````-d```` together

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the above answer the file is a postgres custom dump and can be restored by the command:
pg_restore dump_file -d db_name -U user

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html